# program exits when printing global pointer values in the function passed to glutDisplayFunc()

Tags: c, pointers, glut

I want to take input from user some vertices (x, y). For storing the input, I am using double pointer to integer. After taking input, I am checking if the input is stored correctly.

The input is stored correctly, however, no values are printed in the function passed to `glutDisplayFunc()` and the program is exiting instead.

This is the console output:

```
Number of Vertices:3
Vertices (x, y):
100 0    // values entered by user
0 100
10 10
100 0    // values printed from takeInput()
0 100
10 10

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)    // maybe from myFunction()
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

GLint **points;
int n;

void takeInput(void) {
    printf("Number of Vertices:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    GLint vertices[n][2], *ptrToVertices[n];
    printf("Vertices (x, y):\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        scanf("%d%d", &vertices[i][0], &vertices[i][1]);
        ptrToVertices[i] = vertices[i];
    }
    points = ptrToVertices;

    /* check if input is stored correctly */
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d %d\n", points[i][0], points[i][1]);
    }
}

void myFunction(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d %d\n", points[i][0], points[i][1]);
    }
    // todo
}

void doGlutStuff(int argc, char **argv, char *title, void (*fun)(void)) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutInitWindowSize(1000, 1000);
    glutCreateWindow(title);
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(-500.0, +500.0, -500.0, +500.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glutDisplayFunc(fun);
    glutMainLoop();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    takeInput();
    doGlutStuff(argc, argv, "My Title", myFunction);
    return 0;
}
```

By the way, this is how I am compiling my code:

```
gcc myCode.c -lopengl32 -lfreeglut -lglu32
```

Comment: Nice job formatting and separating your code into functions, but that makes it harder to copy and paste. See my edit for a slightly better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing a pointer to a local variable (`ptrToVertices`) into a global (`points`).  Once `takeInput` returns, `ptrToVertices` no longer exists and the pointer you stored will be left dangling.  (In this case it points to stack memory that will be overwritten and reused.  When you dereference `points` in `myFunction`, you have Undefined Behavior which results in your crash.

One solution would be to use `malloc` to allocate space for your vertices instead of using local variables.